# why I can not use setState value in my code?

Tags: reactjs, fill, setstate

I am trying to create a new array, when I use console.log to check this.state.allColor, I can see the value changed, but when I use the same value of this.state.allColor in creating a new array, it does not work:

```
onValueChange = (e) => {
    const allColor=e.target.value;
    this.setState({allColor})
    const boxes = new Array(this.state.allColor).fill().map(this.randomColor,this)
    this.setState({boxes})
};
```

this does not work as well

```
onValueChange = (e) => {
    const allColor = e.target.value;
    const boxes = new Array(this.setState({allColor})).fill().map(this.randomColor,this)
    console.log(boxes)
};
```

this does not work either

```
onValueChange = (e) => {
    const allColor = e.target.value;
    const allBoxes = this.setState({allColor})
    const boxes=new Array(allBoxes).fill().map(this.randomColor,this)
    console.log(boxes)
};
```

the value of this.state.allColor changes correctly everytime if I use console.log, but I can not use that value in new Array.

but this will work

```
onValueChange=(e) => {
    const totalNumber = 4
    const boxes=new Array(totalNumber).fill().map(this.randomColor,this)
    this.setState({boxes})
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is an [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) operation and therefore, you won't have access to its latest value right away.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component

Also, whenever you call `setState` in your component, you trigger a new `render` to it. So it's better to update your component's state only once to save a little bit of performance as well.

```
onValueChange= (e) => {
  const allColor = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)

  this.setState({
    allColor,
    boxes: new Array(allColor).fill().map(this.randomColor,this)
  })
};
```

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me boxes is not defined error. I have boxes as an empty array in my state.

Comment: @Nhat Have you tried to parse (`parseInt(allColor, 10)`) in the `new Array(..)` part? Maybe that's the reason since `new Array` expects a number and not a string :)

Comment: you are right I check allColor with typeof and they are string instead of number. thanks

Comment: can you correct your answer above so I can accept it? you were right everything works now after I use parseInt thanks

Comment: @Nhat there you go :)